# Put a banner on top of two column cms page in magento

Tags: magento

I created a new CMS with 2column layout and now want to put full width or 1 column banner on top of 2 columns.

I tried

```
<reference name="root">
        <block type="cms/block" name="my_banner" as="my_banner" template="path/to/my_banner.phtml" />
    </reference>
```

in Layout Update XML but nothing happened. Any help will be appreciated!

As per @richtea response I updated the CMS page layout settings like the screenshot given below but didn't worked

http://screencast.com/t/CiidoSRgkNs

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting the page to add a CMS block, but referencing a PHTML template. You can either:

**Insert a CMS block**, use the below and create a block in your admin panel with identifier `my_banner`.

```
<reference name="root">
     <block type="cms/block" name="my_banner">
          <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>my_banner</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Or **insert a template file** as follows

```
<reference name="root">
    <block type="core/template" name="my_banner" as="my_banner" template="path/to/my_banner.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Comment: it is not working ... I updated my question please see screenshot

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your screenshot, provided 'sports-shop-top-banner' cms block exists and is enabled. Change the reference to content or header - does the block show?